# Unable to correctly set the kafka listeners for kafka on pulsar

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-pulsar

We have a already existing pulsar cluster deployed in kubernetes using the helm chart.
We also have a proxy load balancer to talk to the cluster.
To convert this cluster and make it work for kafka, we have added the nar file and mounted it in the correct location. Created a 9092 port.
But in the broker config I am not sure which IP i should give for the kafka listeners mentioned in this document.
https://github.com/streamnative/kop/blob/master/docs/kop.md

Comment: Ideally, you use a DNS hostname, not a ClusterIP to configure ... `listeners` should just be 0.0.0.0 though, but Kafka clients must connect with brokers, not via a load balancer since that would interfere with the Kafka protocol and partition discovery. Everything you need to know about listeners / **advertised listeners** is in the other post. Regarding kubernetes, also checkout https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/06/06/accessing-apache-kafka-in-strimzi-part-1-introduction#what_does_this_mean_for_kafka_on_kubernetes_

Comment: What about the advertised listeners. Is it required?
When I add "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092" as the listener
But when I try to produce kafka message into topic, I get the following error.
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <what should be the ip here?> --topic test

Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: If you set localhost, you're telling the k8s pod it can only be connected to from itself. That's not specific to Kafka protocol. Therefore, 0.0.0.0 tells the server to allow external connections... You additionally need k8s headless service, a ClusterIP, Ingress, External DNS, etc managed by k8s like any other network server running in the cluster. Then you connect with the DNS address or ClusterIP

Comment: These should not be needed for KOP right. I understand its needed if kafka or pulsar is independently deployed.
I am adding kop for an already existing Pulsar cluster. Which already has ingress, cluster ip etc

Comment: `kafkaAdvertisedListeners` is not specific to Kubernetes, and is required for the Kafka protocol to work, yes. The value of this setting should be your Ingress FQDN, not localhost, so that Kafka clients can reach that interface, rather than be redirected at themselves https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/